# Mongo to Mongoose Terminology

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Can some please clarify if the following terms are as I understand them:

Mongo: embedded -> Mongoose: Sub Document

Mongo: referenced documents -> Mongoose: Population

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedded documents and subdocuments are the same thing:

```
{
    "embeddedDoc" : { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 },
    "embeddedDocs" : [
        { "c" : 2, "d" : "cookie" },
        { "s" : 99, "h" : "pie" },
    ]
}
```

Both terms are used when talking about MongoDB and Mongoose. I wouldn't say one is a "MongoDB term" and the other is a "Mongoose term".

A referenced document is a document for which some identifier (usually the `_id`) is stored in another document.

```
{
    "referencedDoc" : "3F6A99E",
    "referencedDocs" : [
        "22AE5",
        "95A11B"
    ]
}
```

In some other collection, or even the same collection, there'd be documents with `_id`s `"3F6A99E"`, `"22AE5"`, and `"95A11B"`. Population is a Mongoose-specific concept. It's the process by which the references are resolved and replaced by the referenced documents, simulating a simple join. For example, after calling `.populate()` with for the field paths `referencedDocs`, you might end up with something like

```
{
    "referencedDoc" : "3F6A99E",
    "referencedDocs" : [
        { "_id" : "22AE5", "food" : "pickles" },
        { "_id" : "95A11B", "food" : "tuna" }
    ]
}
```